# .htaccess Rewrite with authentication

Tags: .htaccess, directory, subdomain, url-rewriting

I've been looking for a htaccess rewrite and authentication solution but I can't understand the rewrite at all :(

What I need is when a user goes to `http://sub.domain.com/folder` or `http://sub.domain.com/folder/` it will be asked for authentication through htaccess but if they go directly to that folder through a different domain they won't be asked for password.

Comment: What do you mean with "they go directly to that folder through a different domain"? Do you have pointing multiple domains to the same folder?

Comment: Yes, let me describe it i build websites and when they are in productions i put them http://sub.domain.com/project.com/ 

and when they are done and approved i point a domain to /home/www/sub/project.com/ 

So when i send the production url to customer i want them to authenticate to see the content or to stop the bots from indexing it.

But when they go to http://project.com/ they will go through without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just to disable directory listing? Put this into .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
```